# How did homonyms come into existence?

Tags: etymology, pronunciation-vs-spelling, homonyms

Words like *bank, bat, bear, fine, fair, number, row*, etc., each have multiple meanings but are pronounced and spelled in the same way.  How can one word mean different things?

Comment: *Number* is not a homonym, but it is a homograph.  *Row* is both a homonym and a homograph. All the rest are homonyms, but not homographs.  *Bear*, *fair* and *row* are all homophones as well as homonyms.  Confused yet?  Homophones are words which are pronounced the same but spelled differently - like *bear* and *bare*; homographs are pronounced differently - like *number* (pronounced "b") and *number* (silent "b"); homonyms are spelled and pronounced the same, but the meanings are different - like *row* (as opposed to "column") and *row* (as in rowing a boat).

Comment: @drɱ65δ I think *homonym* is the general term for same-name, and the specific subtypes are 'homophone' for same-pronunciation and 'homograph' for same-spelling.

Comment: The obvious main two ways are "heteroradical" (having different origins), such as *skate:glide on ice* and *skate:type of fish*, and "polysemous". In "polysemy", the possible meanings of a single word diverge so much we tend to think of the different senses as different words - such as a *bank check (or cheque)*, and *check in chess*.

Comment: The short answer to why one word has to mean different things is because otherwise we'd need nearly 7 billion different words just to uniquely identify all the actual *people* on the planet. And then there's all the dead people, zillions of beetles, and quite a few other things we'd need words for...

Comment: @nohat: I was just about to say (since it didn't fit above) that most people use *[homonym](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/homonym)* to mean *homophone*, and some use it to mean *homograph*.  But its second dictionary definition (the only one exclusive to it, which seems preferable to maintain specificity) is as I stated above.

Comment: @drɱ65δ I think they're all [homonyms](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28699/what-is-a-term-for-words-that-are-both-homophones-and-homographs): Go to the *bank* of the river, then get some money from the *bank*. Use your *bat* to *bat* the *bear* away. I can't *bear* it! It's a *fine* day but I've received a *fine* at the *fair* for my lack of *fair* practices at a *number* of rides. I must go home and *number* the days one *row* at a time until I can *row* my canoe out of here!

Comment: Ah, *number (n)* and *number (v)*.  Yes, you're right!  Now I feel completely justified in having edited the question.

Comment: Or (beloved of cryptic crossword compilers) *number* as *anesthetic*.

Answer (score 3):

According to Steven Pinker, in [The Stuff of Thought](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0670063274):

> Homonymy usually arises when an ancestral word budded off new senses in a language's history and current speakers retain no inkling of the original connection. For instance, the word *odd* originally referred to something that stuck out, like the point of a triangle. Then it was extended to refer to something that metaphorically stuck out because it was unusual, and then was extended further to refer to a number that had one unit sticking out from a pair.

Homophony, on the other hand, is defined as a phenomenon

> in which distinct words are pronounced the same way, usually because their original pronunciations got merged in the history of the language. For example, 
>   *four* and *fore* sound alike today, but *four* originally rhymed with *tour*, and *fore* originally rhymed (more or less) with *flora*; we see fossils of the old pronunciations in the way the words are spelled.

Comment: I think that's Pinker choosing to treat *homonymy* and *homophony* as mutually exclusive categories in his particular context. In practice, *homonymy* is often used as the 'generic' word for several different phenomena.

Comment: Which is too bad, since now when we try to describe words that are spelled and pronounced the same as each other, but with different meanings, we must use a word which can also mean *homophone* or *homograph*.