# Term for words that sound alike but have different meanings and spellings

Tags: pronunciation, terminology

What is the term for words that sound alike but have different spellings and meanings? For example, *there* and *their*.

Comment: Are you looking for something other than [homonym](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homonym)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a term for words that have a single meaning or are only used in a single context?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10614/is-there-a-term-for-words-that-have-a-single-meaning-or-are-only-used-in-a-singl)

Comment: [see also...](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/28700/4972)

Comment: @Phire they're definitely looking for something other than homonym, as homonyms must be homophonic as well as homographic, and they're looking for something heterographic.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Homograph_homophone_venn_diagram.svg

Answer (score 5):

They are *heterographic homophones*. They are also *homophonic heterographs*. All words that sound alike are homophones, and all words that are spelt differently are heterographs, and these are both.

Comment: There are also homographic homonyms, like _bear_ (v) and _bear_ (n), as well as the heterographic ones _bare_ and _Bayer_.

Comment: @JohnLawler well we could define *homonym* as a homographic homophone, but that would include polysemes as well as true homonyms that don't share etymological roots, or at least branched away from each other before moving closer again.