# Word for two words that are similar in pronunciation and writing?

Tags: single-word-requests

This came about as a stray thought I had while reading about a pun that was being translated from a foreign language to English.

It occurred to me that a) in English, we (as in laypeople(?)) generally consider two words that are similar in pronunciation — regardless of symmetry in spelling or meaning — to qualify as a pun (albeit, distinct consonances *or* juxtapositions of their potential interpretations generally seem to have a positive impact to their valuation), and b) due to the nature of the English language, we evaluate the symmetry of said writing based upon "spelling" rather than "the similarity in the physical process of its writing".

What started as a cursory search ended up becoming an interesting read on the various linguistic nomenclature regarding homonyms and related terms.  It would appear that, based upon what information I was able to find, the standard vernacular term that puns most closely identify with should be "synophones", though I could find little supporting information on this word?

And in regards to point `b` above, I'm curious if there's any nomenclatural variations that denote comparability by attributes *other* than spelling (e.g., number of letters, number of syllables, degrees of harmonic cadence ("alliteration" comes to mind, but in the context of individual words), etc.); for example, the original language of the pun I was reading was Japanese Kanji, and being an American-Born Chinese, I am aware of the linguistic import in the "quantity of strokes" such that it is commonly leveraged as a search or input parameter .

Comment: Puns are spoken - they are based on pronunciation. I don't understand your distinction between spelling and 'physical process of writing'.

Comment: *number of letters, number of syllables* - I think you'd just talk about words which are the same length or have the same number of letters or syllables. There isn't a common term, but may be something found in word puzzles.

Comment: Symmetry plays no part in making puns, and it's the context that makes the pun with similar words. Or one word with two meanings. The words begin the pun, but are not the pun.

Comment: Do you mean homophones / near-homophones? If so, this has been asked before: [term for words that sound alike but have different meanings and spellings](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/101589/term-for-words-that-sound-alike-but-have-different-meanings-and-spellings/101593#101593).

Comment: The table herein https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homonym may help answer your query...

Comment: When you state "...similar in pronunciation and writing", it makes more sense that pronunciation could be similar, whereas with writing, I would propose it's either the same or it's not.

Comment: @AlbertFD I was afraid that would be the reaction received since this network is focused on the English language.  The semi-"parity" I was referring to (so to speak) applies in some languages such as Chinese or Japanese, e.g., the words 兄/鬼 which are pronounced similarly (loosely), resemble each other, and require the same amount of "strokes" to write.  Of course, in English there is no such concept, i.e., the letter `A` is still the letter `a` no matter it's case, how many strokes of the pen you take to write it, or how elliptical you make the loop.  I suppose there wouldn't be any specific..

Comment: ..terminology coined since it doesn't apply to the native language?

Comment: And regarding the Wiki article you cited, that was the exact table I was referring to in my OP, where I first saw the term "synophone".  However, further attempts to research this term proved fruitless.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks for this, I discounted "homophones" due to the qualifying criteria of having the same pronunciation, but this is the first I'm hearing about "near-homophones".  I think this sufficiently answers the first half of my inquiry, and I'd presume the second half doesn't have an answer since it's not a native feature of the English language?

Comment: @KateBunting Yes, I'm aware of this distinction, but in the English-speaking community that reads novels translated over from foreign languages, there are often elements of humor or other nuances that would otherwise normally be lost in translation.  Often, the translator will include a footnote explaining the original context for those who are interested, and for cases such as the one I am referring to the vernacular term used is — for better or worse — "puns".  I'm posting this inquiry exactly because I'm curious what experts of the English language think from a nomenclatural standpoint.

Comment: @YosefBaskin My apologies if I've incorrectly applied the term, I did attempt to (somewhat) allude to what you've spoken about when I mentioned "consonances or juxtapositions".  If I'm understanding your point correctly, do you mean to say that the focal point of my inquiry — which I'll refer to as "near-homophones" for lack of a better term — is not itself the "pun", but is instead a constituent of which a pun is comprised of?  Nonetheless, given my inadequate diction, I would be at a loss for how better to refer to the lexical device in question with due specificity and efficacy.

Comment: If the untranslatable humour depends on a word or phrase having two possible meanings, it's a pun or 'play on words'.

Comment: There are many features of the English language that have individual terms. And many that don't.