# Is there a name for spelling differences in words like _grey/gray_, _color/colour_, etc.?

Tags: word-usage, orthography

Is there a categorical name for differences in the spelling of a word when the word keeps the same meaning and the same sound?

Comment: "variants"? but in the cases you provide the issue is one of geography so they are functions of dialect, not variants within the same dialect.

Comment: Whey are not "words ... that are spelled differently". They are variant spellings of _the same word_.

Comment: *“Anyone who can only think of one way to spell a word obviously lacks imagination.”* ―Mark Twain

Comment: [The picture here](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/28700/4972) says that it is a 'different spelling'.

Comment: They're not, but they *should* be called **homologues**.

Comment: @Dan: Not entirely. The *colour/color* is strongly dialectally/geographically delineated, but *grey/gray* is much more of a grey area. I use both, and don't really think about it.

Comment: @tchrist:  I agree with Twain.  To spell a word only one way is stewpid!

Comment: I nominate **heterograph**.

Answer (score 2):

In general, *spelling variants* or *alternative spellings*.

More specifically, when one is vastly predominate in one form of English, *regional spelling variants*.

Comment: While there is some regional variation going on when it comes to what we call these things, *regional* works much better with *spelling variants* than it does with *alternate* or *alternative*. That said, *alternate* is more common than *alternative* when placed immediately before the noun (without the word *regional*). http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=alternate+spelling%2Calternative+spelling&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=

Answer (score 1):

Alternate spellings or spelling variants--I prefer *alternate spelling* but [see notes below for which is more common where](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/104122/is-there-a-name-for-the-category-of-words-that-includes-grey-gray-color-colour-e/104126#comment212033_104126). The title of this post lists some British and American variations in spelling.

[Oxford Dictionaries](http://oxforddictionaries.com/words/british-and-american-spelling) has a good overview of some of the differences between the UK and the US, and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_and_British_English_spelling_differences) has a pretty big article on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

*"Alternate spellings"* and *"spelling variants"* both directly make sense.

Answer (score -1):

These are variant spellings. (Of course, the Commonwealth could have a body that could rule on the matter, based on which the most common pattern the word should follow. But, of course, no one cares about the million of kids who struggle to learn this hideous and flawed spelling system and no one cares to follow spelling rules either! Kids, why don't YOU follow rules? Complete laissez-faire is dangerous in economics and in ... linguisics. When will THEY get it? RULE(s) ... Britania?)

Comment: This is of course why English is such a minority language and languages like Irish and Basque which do have such official standards dominate International communication...

Answer (score -2):

I suggest

> Homophonic synonyms.

Comment: props for coining the expression, but ultimately no, since the question is about same word variations in spelling.

Comment: @Adam - Fair enough, I had read the question but not its title. Why not call them _spelling variants_?

Comment: *Spelling variants* works. On Google ngrams[1], *Alternate spellings* is more common in American English, and *spelling variants* is slightly more popular in the UK. Overall, they're equally common expressions. [1]http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=spelling+variants%2Calternate+spellings%2Cvariations+in+spelling&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=